# Android material button taking color primary instead of color accent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, android-styles, material-components-android

I have my layout button as -

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
  android:id="@+id/save_button"
  style="@style/buttonView"
  android:text="Save"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

In my `styles.xml`, I have -

```
<style name="buttonView" parent="Theme.MyTheme">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

In my `themes.xml`, I have -

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!--- Accent color. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant
        </item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

As per the Android documentation all the UI elements such as FAB, textview, edit text, button take the color accent. So I expect my button to take the `colorAccent` by default but why does it take `colorPrimary`. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#theming-buttons).

The filled button has the `backgroundTint` based on the **`colorPrimary`**.
Also in your `buttonView` style you should extend one of the provided styles:

```
Default style           Widget.MaterialComponents.Button
Icon style              Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon
Unelevated style.       Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton
Unelevated icon style   Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton.Icon
```

Example:

```
<style name="buttonView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">

</style>
```

If you want to change the background color you can:

- Use the `backgroundTint` attribute in your custom style
- Override the `colorPrimary` attribute in your custom style using the **`materialThemeOverlay`** (best solution)

Example:

```
<style name="buttonView"parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/CustomButtonThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButtonThemeOverlay">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi @Gabriele you post some great answers on MDC content, I am wondering if there is a bug in Material 3 with `materialThemeOverlay` related to this answer - I have a question here if you have 2 mins https://stackoverflow.com/q/71887041/1866373

Answer (score 1):

For my case this problem comes around when updating android studio to version 4.1.. button background color, always get color primary purple_500 by default. your code does not have problem. I set backgroundTint attribute to null and background attribute to favorite color, or just set backgroundTint to favorite color.

Comment: Using the `background` and `backgroundTint` attributes is not the same. Using `background` the `MaterialButton` doesn't use its own `MaterialShapeDrawable` for the background. This means that features like shape appearance, stroke and rounded corners are ignored.