# Instead of unexpected purple, how to use white default color for button?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-button, android-theme

When I add button widgets it shows purple color, but I want to remove it and change to default white color.
I have terminated all my previous projects and created a new project but still this problem occurs.
What should I do in this matter?

This is a button which I want to change into default white color:

[image: button-example]

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751455/android-material-button-taking-color-primary-instead-of-color-accent

Answer (score 2):

To achieve hive this you must have to change the background color of the button to

```
android:background ="#FFFFFF"
```

And the reason may of purple color is that you didn't give it a custom color so android studio set it as color primary which is purple by default.

Answer (score 2):

i solved that problem by using in attributs --->backgroundTint and put any color you want

or by code=>nameOfButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.anycolor);

Answer (score 1):

Also had this problem and I had to just set the background color of my Button.

I think it's caused by the `themes.xml` and `themes.xml (night)`